# How to locate the element with text Not Now within Instagram using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, instagram

Element shapshot:

[image]

As it can be seen from the image I can locate the element but it does not click on it. Do you think it needs explicit wait or something else?
Thank you!

Comment: in the browser you can go Inspect > copy > copy selector/copy xpath. Those don't work when you put the selectors into the program?

Comment: Is there any iframe?

Comment: I think I found the solution. I just added implicitwait right before the "Frame"(it is not an iframe) it seems to be working. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Not Now** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("section +div>button"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click();
  ```